# Bringing convenience of Java code assistant from Eclipse to Visual Studio 2010 for native C++ projects

Tags: c++, eclipse, visual-studio-2010

Eclipse has many features which saves a developer much time, for example:

1) Override/Implement Methods...[image]

2) TODO lists...
[image]

3) Fast access to documentation... (There might be also something else) [image]

Is there any plugin for VS 2010 which brings approximately the same functionality to native C++ projects?

Comment: Does Eclipse CDT have the `Override/Implement Methods` option? Your screenshot looks like it was taken from the Java perspective.

Comment: You're right, it's java perspective, I updated the question.

Comment: Note that Visual Studios already has TODO lists based on searching project source. You can access it from `View`->`Task List`. It has two modes: "Comments" and "User Tasks". Comments mode searches "hack: *" and "todo: *".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VisualAssist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) provides refactoring, navigation and code assistance. When you're moving from Eclipse to VisualStudio, it drastically reduces the feeling that you're working with stone knives and bearskins.